# Forcing to be a scalar

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
while (<>)
{ chomp;
say reverse;  
}
```

The above code doesn't work but when I change 2nd last line to `say scalar reverse;` then it works fine. Why do I need to force it to be a scalar explicitly? Can't Perl DWIM?

Comment: While testing this, there seems to be some inconsistency in when `reverse` implicitly uses `$_`, i.e. it does use `$_` in scalar context, but not in list context. (`@a = reverse` vs `$a = reverse`) Is this a bug, or working as intended?

Comment: Yes, I found the same bug (if it is). Have to define $_ explicitly.

Comment: @TLP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871120/reverse-doesnt-use-implicitly-in-list-context-is-this-a-bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the documentation right, `reverse` normally operates on lists. In a list context used without arguments, it returns an empty list and by default doesn't assign it anywhere. In your example, say outputs the unchanged `$_`;

Forcing `reverse` into scalar context changes its behaviour and makes it reverse character strings, and use `$_` by default. Because `say` can be used to print lists as well as scalars, it doesn't force its arguments into scalar context.

Perl probably does DWIM, just for given values of "I".

A breakdown of what reverse does when:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use v5.12;

my $inscalar = "foo bar";

# `reverse` is in list context, $in is coerced to a single-element list
my @outlist = reverse $inscalar;

# `reverse` is in scalar context, so it reverses strings
my $outscalar = reverse $inscalar;

say join(" | ", @outlist); # prints "foo bar"
say $outscalar; # prints "rab oof"

# the "normal" behaviour of `reverse`
my @inlist = qw(foo bar);
@outlist = reverse @inlist;
say join(" | ", @outlist); # prints "bar | foo"
```

Comment: Assuming `$_ = "foo bar"`, then `@a = reverse` and `@a = reverse $_` should yield the same result. This, however, is not the case.

Comment: @TLP You're right. It seems like `reverse` without arguments in list context is just a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do I need to force it to be a scalar explicitly?

As [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), `reverse` reverses the order of the elements of the argument list when used in list context. For example, `reverse 'a', 'b', 'c'` returns `'c', 'b', 'a'`.

> Can't Perl DWIM?

Yes, it could do what you want (scalar behaviour when no argument expression is present).

It could be confusing, though. I can't think of any other operator that changes behaviour based on a lack of an argument expression (as opposed to just lack of arguments).

Comment: There is something strange here. I am not getting the same result for `@array = reverse` and `@array = reverse $_`, but I do get the intended result with `$var = reverse`. So, `reverse` uses `$_` implicitly, *except* in list context?

Comment: Yes. A bare `reverse` is only treated as `reverse $_` in scalar context. This is in `perldoc -f reverse`: "Used without arguments *in scalar context*, `reverse()` reverses `$_`."

Comment: @socketpuppet You're right, it is documented. Of sorts. Feels unfamiliar to have a function that does *not* use `$_` by default with missing arguments, but instead uses... nothing? And does not even give a warning about it. Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks @socket puppet, Removed false claim that `say reverse;` means `say reverse $_;`