# reverse doesn't use $_ implicitly in list context, is this a bug?

Tags: perl

```
@array = reverse; 
and 
@array = reverse $_;
```

Both are different. `@array = reverse` doesn't use `$_` implicitly. We have to declare `$_` explicitly. It's a very strange case where `$_` is not being used by default. Is it a bug?

Comment: Think about it.  What do you get when you reverse a list containing one item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understand from the [reverse documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), `reverse` works on arrays, and so it should use `@_` rather than the scalar `$_`?

The documentation says "Used without arguments in **scalar context**, `reverse()` reverses `$_`." [Emphasis added]

```
$_ = "dlrow ,olleH";
print reverse;                              # No output, list context
print scalar reverse;                       # Hello, world
```

Answer (score 4):

Whatever is in the official documentation is the Perl specification. If Perl does what the docs say it should do, then it is not a bug. It is a language design and implementation decision.